# 1 Action get lastinsertedID for 2 inserts/adds with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, identity

I have an action and 2 SQL tables I know how to enter a record into 1 table but for the second table I want to get the lastly inserted ID from table 1 and insert that into the 2nd table for one of the columns. I have everything setup but my database save doesn’t work without an exception. Also Im not sure how to use scope_identity() or get the last ID and I am using EF for everything.

```
public ActionResult AddTimeSheet()
        {
            ViewBag.ProjectsSelect = new SelectList(
                context.Projects.ToList(), "ProjectId", "ProjectName");

            var uid = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            ViewBag.CurrentId = uid;

            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult AddTimeSheet(TimeSheetProjectsModel timeSheetModel)
        {
            try
            {
                if(timeSheetModel == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
                //if (ModelState.IsValid)
                //{
                    TimeSheetMaster masterModel = new TimeSheetMaster();
                    masterModel.FromDate = timeSheetModel.Proj1;
                    masterModel.ToDate = timeSheetModel.Proj1.AddDays(7);
                    /* NEED HRS 4 WEEK/END MONTH/NEW MONTH */

                    masterModel.TotalHours = timeSheetModel.ProjTotal1;
                    masterModel.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                    masterModel.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
                    /* MONTH SUBMITTED */

                    masterModel.TimeSheetStatus = 1;
                    masterModel.Comment = timeSheetModel.ProjDesc1;
                    context.TimeSheetMaster.Add(masterModel);

                    var detailsModel = CreateTimeSheetDetails(masterModel, timeSheetModel);
                    context.TimeSheetDetails.Add(detailsModel);
                    context.SaveChanges();

                    TempData["SuccessMaster"] = "TimeSheetMaster Created Successfully";
                    TempData["SuccessDetails"] = "TimeSheetDetails Created Successfully";
                    return RedirectToAction("TimeSheetList", "TimeSheet");
                //}
               // TempData["Error"] = "TimeSheet Create Was Unsuccessful";
               // return RedirectToAction("TimeSheetList", "TimeSheet");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
                TempData["Error"] = "TimeSheet Create Was Unsuccessful";
                return RedirectToAction("TimeSheetList", "TimeSheet");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two entities are associated with the same DbContext and they are directly related, (PK/FK) then the best solution is to ensure that the entities have a navigation property set up for the relation and let EF manage the keys and linking.

For instance:

```
TimeSheetMaster masterModel = new TimeSheetMaster();
masterModel.FromDate = timeSheetModel.Proj1;
masterModel.ToDate = timeSheetModel.Proj1.AddDays(7);
masterModel.TotalHours = timeSheetModel.ProjTotal1;
masterModel.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
masterModel.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
masterModel.TimeSheetStatus = 1;
masterModel.Comment = timeSheetModel.ProjDesc1;

var detailsModel = CreateTimeSheetDetails(masterModel, timeSheetModel);
// either here, or inside CreateTimeSheetDetails...
// if Master has a collection of Details: (1-to-Many)
masterModel.Details.Add(details);
// or if Master has a 1-to-1 relationship to details.
// masterModel.Details = detailsModel;

context.TimeSheetMaster.Add(masterModel);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Ideally EF should manage your relationships so that your code simply works with the related entity structure and hands off the key/relationship management to Entity Framework.

If you need IDs cross-context, or to return after performing an insert then you can access the entity's new PK directly after calling `SaveChanges`:

```
context.TimeSheetMaster.Add(masterModel);
context.SaveChanges();
var newId = masterModel.TimeSheetMasterId; // Populated automatically after SaveChanges.
```